# Loading .a (static library) file using NSBundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsbundle

How to load .a file in objective-c programmatically.
And how to get type of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries (`.a`) cannot be loaded at runtime. They can only be used as input to the linker (that is, at compile time).

If you want to load a library at runtime, you will need to use a dynamic library (`.dylib`, or a plugin bundle). Refer to Apple's [Introduction to Dynamically Loading Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html) for details, or ask another question if you have a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff... So i created a dynamic library LibCT.dylib. Now i want to use this library in my application(cocoa). What are the steps are required to load and use that library?